# Error message using TFS/TeamCity builds

Tags: .net, teamcity

What can this mean? Please help. I am using TFS, TeamCity and I am getting this error with TeamCity automated builds.

> ERROR - Could not load file or assembly 'System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral,  PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>   System.Exception: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>   File name: 'System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'
>      at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsTeamProjectCollection.GetFullyQualifiedUriForName(String name)
>      at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TeamFoundationServer..ctor(String url, ICredentials credentials)
>      at JetBrains.TeamCity.Tfs.TfsHelpers.Create(String server, String username, String password) in c:\Agent\work\7b38d9d0edb21a5b\TfsNativeAccessor\src\TfsHelpers.cs:line 97
>      at JetBrains.TeamCity.Tfs.Command.Do() in c:\Agent\work\7b38d9d0edb21a5b\TfsNativeAccessor\src\Command.cs:line 23
>      at JetBrains.TeamCity.Tfs.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\Agent\work\7b38d9d0edb21a5b\TfsNativeAccessor\src\Program.cs:line 118

Comment: As it says, It cant load some of the .NET assemblies. Are you sure you have  .NET 3.5 properly installed on that system?

Comment: I have .NET 4 installed. but this talks about 3.5.. or do you think my .net 4 install is bad?

Comment: .NET 4 isnt the same as 3.5, the version is checked with strong typed assemblies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure thatn .Net Framework 3.5.0.0 is installed in your system. In addition, does your builds have been configured to run on a remote agent? If yes, you should have it installed on all the agents that build .net projects.

Comment: I have .net4 installed. Agent is on the server itself, so dont have to worry about installing on all agents. Do I still need 3.5 if I already have 4

Comment: Yes, strong-named assemblies are checked by their version at load time, so you need to have the exact assemblies by name, version, culture and public key.